# Does not connect to oracle pluggable database

Tags: oracle, liquibase, sqlclient, sqlcl, oracle21c

I wanted to execute 'lb generate-schema -split' after installing liquibase and sqlcli but when I hit the above command it doesn't connect to pluggable database (xepdb1). It always tried to connect to 'xe' or 'orcl' service names. Can anybody help me to solve the issue?

```
D:\Software\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin>sql


SQLcl: Release 23.1 Production on Sat Apr 29 12:27:03 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Username? (''?) apexuser@**xepdb1**

Password? (**********?) **********

Last Successful login time: Sat Apr 29 2023 12:27:17 +09:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> lb generate-schema -split
--Starting Liquibase at 12:27:24 (version 4.17.0 #0 built at 2022-11-02 21:48+0000)

  USER          = apexuser
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:oci8:@
  Error Message = ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  USER          = apexuser
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
  Error Message = Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
  (CONNECTION_ID=zW40jSIGS5KejZYrbKvK/A==)
  USER          = apexuser
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't connect to pluggable database (**xepdb1**). It always tried to connect to '**xe**' or '**orcl**' service names

As it says, what used to be true, isn't true any more. It depends on how you named the database (or left to Oracle to decide), and in *newer* XE databases it is `xepdb1`.

This is my XE database (I *know* its name; I'm just displaying what's in my TNSNAMES.ORA):

```
c:\temp>tnsping pdb1

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 29-APR-2023 06:27:14

Copyright (c) 1997, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Users\littlefoot\Documents\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lf_laptop)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)))
OK (60 msec)
```

See the `SERVICE_NAME` at the very end of the previous line?

```
c:\temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@lf_laptop:1521/xepdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Apr 29 06:27:52 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Apr 14 2023 21:02:45 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Therefore, try the same with Liquibase; I don't use it so I can't assist with it, but I presume that this should be modified:

```
URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xepdb1
                                                 ------
                                                 this
```